# cordova windows error: "cordova/windows8/commandProxy" not found

Tags: windows, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have built a Cordova-based Windows application. As soon as I add any plugin, the app starts crashing with the exception `cordova/windows8/commandProxy not found`.

Cordova version: 4.3.0

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so, you might want to mark it as such.

Answer (score 12):

It seems that `cordova/windows8/commandProxy` is deprecated in Cordova 4.3.0.

I have replaced this statement in plugin file

```
require("cordova/windows8/commandProxy")
```

to

```
require("cordova/exec/proxy")
```

and it seems to work.

For example I changed line number 18 in PushPluginProxy.js from

```
require("cordova/windows8/commandProxy").add("PushPlugin", module.exports);
```

to

```
require("cordova/exec/proxy").add("PushPlugin", module.exports);
```

The name in the string varies depending on the plugin.

Alternatively, you can patch the plugin like in [this pull request from the AppVersion plugin](https://github.com/deliriousrhino/cordova-plugin-app-version/commit/819ab599a80b51f7c53d04905081ef38d2b31db9) i.e.:

Change

```
require("cordova/windows8/commandProxy").add("AppVersion", AppVersionProxy);
```

to

```
cordova.commandProxy.add("AppVersion", AppVersionProxy);
```

Comment: This works for me. Great answer. I hope the questioner will accept it soon to help others.