# JavaScript runtime error: module cordova/windows8/commandProxy not found

Tags: cordova, command

I got this error "JavaScript runtime error: module cordova/windows8/commandProxy not found" when i open my cordova application in the visual studio; And it's windows 8. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: any solutions  found ?

Comment: This might be the answer you were looking for
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069134/cordova-windows-error-cordova-windows8-commandproxy-not-found#_=_