# Import working cordova project in Visual Studio giving errors

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

**TL;DR** 
When I'm importing my existing Cordova project in Visual Studio and run the application in my browser (through Ripple) I'll get the following error:
`PushPlugin.register - We seem to be missing some stuff :(`

**Full explanation:**
First of all apologies for the long post, I wanted to include as much information as possible! 
I have a working Cordova application that I run with Ionic, Cordova and Ripple. I use Ripple to emulate mobile devices in my browser.

All of the features work perfectly when I test it in Sublime Text Editor and run with `ripple emulate`.
When I try to import the project in Visual Studio, it doesn't run as smoothly.

I'll explain what I did in steps, because perhaps I missed something in a particular step.

### Step 1

This is my code from my config.xml in my Sublime project (not Visual Studio).

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.4.0" />
```

This is the config.xml in Visual Studio. Note the `com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin`. This is a plugin available on github, but I could only find a direct link to the `2.5` version. In managed to download the zip to the `2.4` version though, so I added it through this way.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" version="4.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" version="1.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" version="1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" version="1.2.1" />
<plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" version="2.4.0" src="D:\Dev\A\VisualStudioApp\VisualStudioApp\local-plugins\PushPlugin-2.4.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-websql" version="0.0.10" />
```

### Step 2

This is the folder structure in my Sublime Text Editor:

```
<DIR>          fonts
<DIR>          icons
<DIR>          images
<DIR>          iscroll
<DIR>          jquery-mobile
<DIR>          js
-   <DIR>          app
-   <DIR>          lib
<DIR>          platforms
<DIR>          res
<DIR>          slickgrid
<DIR>          styles
<DIR>          testdata
        27 295 MobileProject.jsproj
           588 MobileProject.jsproj.user
         4 115 config.xml
           999 config.xml.bak
           938 config.xml.vs
       222 115 cordova.android.js
       209 664 cordova.ios.js
        60 180 cordova.js
             2 cordova_plugins.js
         1 142 footer.html
           313 header.html
           212 index.html
        67 607 main.html
```

And here is the folder structure inside Visual Studio:

```
<DIR>          bin
<DIR>          bld
<DIR>          local-plugins
<DIR>          merges
<DIR>          platforms
<DIR>          plugins
<DIR>          res
<DIR>          testdata
<DIR>          www
-   <DIR>          fonts
-   <DIR>          icons
-   <DIR>          images
-   <DIR>          iscroll
-   <DIR>          jquery-mobile
-   <DIR>          js
    -    <DIR>          app
    -    <DIR>          lib
-   <DIR>          slickgrid
-   <DIR>          styles
-            1 142 footer.html
-              313 header.html
-              212 index.html
-           67 607 main.html
        131 .gitignore
         75 bower.json
        225 build.json
      6 686 VisualStudioApp.jsproj
        309 VisualStudioApp.jsproj.user
      7 146 config.xml
        122 package.json
    124 250 Project_Readme.html
         34 taco.json
```

### Step 3

Run the application on Android 
[image: Run application]

This is what my console log gives me: 
`GET http://localhost:4400/config.xml 404 (Not Found) ripple.js:51`
`No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin. whitelist.js:24`
[image: Result]

### Sidenotes

- When I add the plugins, but don't copy the code from Sublime to Visual Studio, no errors will be shown.
- When I run the application on Windows-AnyCPU (Local Machine), the application will start and almost instantly shut down.
- In debug mode I've bumped into an exception at the start of the run:

`SCRIPT5022: Unhandled exception at line 59, column 13 in ms-appx://io.cordova.myapp4a33c5/www/cordova.js
0x800a139e - Runtime-fout JavaScript: module cordova/windows8/commandProxy not found
cordova.js (59,13)`
What is this `cordova/windows8/commandProxy`?

Answer (score 0):

(I am assuming you have the correct version of Node installed)

What version of Visual Studio you have? I am using Visual Studio 2015 and here are the steps I have taken to import my projects.

1. Unzipped it to a place I want my project to be.
2. On Visual studio menu File --> Open --> Project/Solution and Selected my folder where all the files are.
3. You will see and upward arrow icon says Dependencies right under your Solution. Expand it and you will see 2 folders Bower and NPM. Right click and Select Restore Package. This might take some time.

After that, try use the command version and use "ionic serve". This should bring it on a webpage.

For your Cordova proxy question, Check the following link out
[cordova windows error: “cordova/windows8/commandProxy” not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069134/cordova-windows-error-cordova-windows8-commandproxy-not-found)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646749/cordova-plugin-listpicker-error-on-ripple-emulator/34652788#34652788). Although it's not the exact same error message, the problem is the same.

Ripple is not a complete simulation of a real device, there is no support for many plugins, such as the PushPlugin you're using. Try running your app on a real device or an emulator to fix the error.

Comment: Valid point there. The problem is that I want to make a Windows Application and I should normally be able to run that within Visual Studio. But all I'm getting is the loading screen from Cordova and then the application shuts down instantly.

Comment: Alright, what Windows version are you running on? Have you configured your config.xml to match your Windows version? Like `<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />` for Windows 10...